# Errors in my error_log file which are not mine? How can its possible?

Tags: php, cpanel

Im on shared hosting with cPanel. So my problem is that, I regularly got error messages from another servers/hostings which are not mine to my error log.
(Also I asked my hosting provider with no luck)

These errors looks like this:

```
[05-May-2022 09:34:37 Europe/Budapest] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[05-May-2022 09:34:37 Europe/Budapest] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/szhwnazp/public_html/wordfence-waf.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
[05-May-2022 09:50:35 Europe/Budapest] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[05-May-2022 09:50:35 Europe/Budapest] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/jtqwzr/sssss.hu/admin/adw_filler.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
[05-May-2022 10:00:43 Europe/Budapest] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[05-May-2022 10:00:43 Europe/Budapest] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/qrdugpav/public_html/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
[05-May-2022 10:03:22 Europe/Budapest] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[05-May-2022 10:03:22 Europe/Budapest] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/omsktxoj/public_html/index.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I got 20-30-40 around error messages / day.

The errors are always the same: Unknown: Failed opening required / Unknown: failed to open stream

What can cause this? Thank you!

Comment: Seems like maybe you have a shared log file. Contact the hosting company to enquire

Comment: _"What can cause this?"_ - some sort of configuration- / setup-error on the provider side. I really don't see how anyone _but_ your hosting provider could help with this.

Comment: they said they didn't found any problems with the server configuration and they can't help me.. I dont get any other error but only these with failed opening and failed to open stream. It is very annoying to always filter out these errors.

Comment: BTW. Its started when I changed the error_log directory in PHP Selector in cPanel.

Comment: If you have the access log, you can see where its called from.